# Comunicación uni-direccional entre aplicaciones

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Que Metodo, Patron, Diseño o Implementacion puede servir para la **actualizacion** de campos de una **Aplicacion A** (WPF, C#, Patron MVVM) desde una segunda **Aplicacion B**. *Ambas aplicaciones se encontrarian en el mismo equipo.*

Actualmente estoy pensando en crear un **self-contained WebService** dentro de la `Aplicacion A` para ser consumidos por la `Aplicacion B`, pero me gustaria tener segundas opiniones sobre el metodo mas efectivo y MVVM-friendly para afontar esta dificultad.

Comment: Hola, la aplicación a desarrollar es UWP? Si es así puedes implementar un [App Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia, ya que para comunicación entre procesos tienes muchisimas opciones. Pudes usar un webservice como indicas, App Service como te indica @SergioParra, podrias utilizar sockets, incluso un archivo de texto. Las opciones son muchas, cada una con ventajas e inconvenientes dependiendo del uso que vayas a darle.